# Is this possible, or valid, in HTML and PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

Can I put this in my HTML `<head>`?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://site.com/some/php/script/userid/style.php" />
```

Basically, can I pass a user ID via a URI segment (or a GET variable) to a PHP script - which will still be validly treated as a stylesheet?

So, for example, if in my webapp a user has a custom CSS stylesheet for their page, I can just load it up dynamically in my controller by outputting this as the stylesheet URL - is this possible? I know the PHP part is certainly possible, but will this still be valid or fully browser/server compatible?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you simply try it and see by yourself? it would have been about as long than writing your question.

Comment: @Valentin I see your point, but this is a valid question: There are many intricacies and delicacies to this that aren't completely obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming you're asking "will this work?" and not "is this valid HTML?" for that, See @Gordon's answer.

If your PHP script outputs a `text/css` content type and valid CSS, this will work fine.

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
```

This header is necessary for FF to interpret the CSS. See [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aBOkQyfDxrzcJ%3ahttps://developer.mozilla.org/en/incorrect_mime_type_for_css_files%20firefox%20css%20content%20type%20mdc&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de&source=www.google.de) why.

It will be desirable to add some caching headers as well, otherwise the resource will probably be requested on every page load.

**However...**

If you need to output dynamic CSS,  consider having a static style sheet (i.e. one that does **not** get interpreted by PHP)  with all the generic stuff, and adding dynamic data in the document's head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://site.com/resources/style.css" />

<style type="text/css">
  .userText { color: <?php echo $userTextColor; `> }
  etc. etc. 
</style>
```

this way, the CSS resource can remain a static file. It will not require starting a PHP process to get served. If your CSS parameters change from page to page, this will save you a HTTP request.

Comment: Great answer, and thanks for making the 'However' suggestions too! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is valid HTML. For the validity of the HTML document, the only thing that's important is that the [href attribute points to a URI.](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html)

```
<!ELEMENT link EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST link
  %attrs;
  charset     %Charset;      #IMPLIED
  href        %URI;          #IMPLIED
  hreflang    %LanguageCode; #IMPLIED
  type        %ContentType;  #IMPLIED
  rel         %LinkTypes;    #IMPLIED
  rev         %LinkTypes;    #IMPLIED
  media       %MediaDesc;    #IMPLIED
  >
```

You can check the validity of your document with http://validator.w3.org/check

#### But …

The script that is located at that URI has to serve any content with the correct header so the **browser** can actually interpret it as CSS. This is a completely different thing than HTML validity though. So for serving a CSS file, you have to set the text/css header.

Note that using this approach is generally discouraged though [unless you implement some sort of caching mechanism](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/3-ways-to-compress-css-files-using-php). When you point to a PHP file, the webserver will execute the PHP file so you lose any caching mechanism you'd usually have for static resources.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you output proper CSS it fine. Your browser doesn't care how the stylesheet is generated or how the URI looks like. It just has to be a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you have correct headers set, there should not be any problems with that.